# how do I create a generator for shell communication in python?

Tags: python, shell, generator

I want to create a generator for communicating with processes through the shell.
So far what I have is this:

```py
def shell():
    with Popen(["bash"], stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE) as p:
        while True:
            yield p.communicate(str.encode((yield)))[0]
```

That of course has two problems.

- it crashes very easily
- the communication is weird since there are two yields for every iteration of the `while` loop

Any ideas?

Comment: Errm, why do you want to do this?

Comment: @barny i want to mimic shell commands from somewhere else. i don't care that much about it being a generator, but that seems like a good idea